# Error With SqlCommand not accepting Parameter Arguments

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I am trying to execute on a stored procedure in my database with the following code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCNN"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.myStoredProcedure", connection))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = number;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NickName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = "stlukeshs";                            
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            //Do Stuff..
        }
        //closer reader
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

However, on execution I am getting an error that says:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Procedure or function 'myStoredProcedure' expects parameter '@PatientId', which was not supplied.

Clearly you see I am adding the parameters, and my value for `number` is 100, not null.  So I am a bit confused on why it is not getting my parameter arguments.

Comment: That's clearly not your real stored procedure name, so presumably other things may not quite be as in the real code... are you 100% sure this isn't a typo?

Comment: I'm surprised it would not complain about you not opening the connection.

Comment: Oh it did, I missed that line of code.. sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `CommandType` which is `Text` in default. You have to specify `StoredProcedure` as `CommandType` i.e.

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

So, your complete code should be :

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCNN"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.myStoredProcedure", connection))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PatientId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = number;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NickName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = "stlukeshs";                            
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            //Do Stuff..
        }
        //closer reader
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed my problem exactly.  I thought that would have been implicit, alas I am wrong.  Thank you!